# SQL Query to Delete Text Within a Cell That Begins and Ends with Specific Text

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete data from a column that begins and ends with specific text.

I have 800 records, the data between the text I want to remove is different in all the 800 records.

For example:
This house is big /br/br link img src house.png /br

I want to delete everything between the /br/br and the /br.

How would I write this query?

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the column?

Comment: Please be clear. What you say sounds more like an 'UPDATE' ? And it'd be good if you can give a proper example

Comment: I actually want to delete the text or data between the /br/br and /br in the sample above. My apologies, it seems that you read the question when I was editing. I want to delete the text mentioned not sure if this is updating.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
update t
set s = concat (
        substr(s, 1, locate('/br/br', s) + 5),
        substr(s, length(s) - locate('rb/', reverse(s)) - 1)
        )
where s like '%/br/br%br%';
```

Used `locate` to find the index of the point to find substrings and then use concat to join the desired parts together.

It deletes everything between first `/br/br` and last `/br`